# CS0201 error in ICommand impmentation for WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, command

I develop a WPF application, obviously, I use MVVM pattern. Without an external library (MvvmCross, MvvmLight, ...)

And I've tried to implement `ICommand`:

#### Option 1

```
public class Command : ICommand
{
    private readonly Func<bool> _canExecute;
    private readonly Action _action;

    public Command1(Action action, Func<bool> canExecute)
    {
        _action = action;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => true;

    public void Execute(object parameter) => _action();
}
```

#### Option 2

```
public class Command : ICommand
{
    private readonly Func<bool> _canExecute;
    private readonly Action<object> _action;

    public Command1(Action<object> action, Func<bool> canExecute)
    {
        _action = action;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => true;

    public void Execute(object parameter) => _action(parameter);
}
```

#### Option 3

...with some delegates

```
public class Command : ICommand
{
    private readonly Func<object, bool> _canExecute;
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;

    public Command(Action<object> execute) => _execute = execute ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(execute));

    public Command(Action execute)
        : this((Action<object>)delegate { execute(); })
    {
        if (execute == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(execute));
        }
    }

    public Command(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute)
        : this(execute) => _canExecute = canExecute ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(canExecute));

    public Command(Action execute, Func<bool> canExecute)
        : this(delegate
        {
            execute();
        }, (object o) => canExecute())
    {
        if (execute == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(execute));
        }
        if (canExecute == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(canExecute));
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => _canExecute != null ? _canExecute(parameter) : true;

    public void Execute(object parameter) => _execute(parameter);
}
```

In all cases:

```
public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public ICommand MyCommand = new Command(() => MyVoid());
    private void MyVoid()
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

```
public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public ICommand MyCommand = new Command(MyVoid);
    private void MyVoid()
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

I've a CS0201 error (Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement).

I don't understand why.

In other projects, which use MVVM pattern (Xamarin.Forms, Xamarin, ...), I use `Xamarin.Forms.Command` or `MvxCommand` (MvvmCross) and it works...

Comment: On which line do you get the error?

Comment: Have you tried to declare a command action as `() => MyVoid())`? or even `new Command(MyVoid)`

Comment: Also, you shouldn't ignore the `canExecute` delegate in first two options

Comment: Are you sure the error relates to your command instantiation? It doesn't look like this to  me. Maybe you should post your exact code here. Your current instantiation code would not compile, I guess. Instead of initializing a property, you are initializing a field, which is not allowed by the compiler. Don't know if this is a typo...

Answer (score 0):

I don't suggest to name the realying class `Command` because you may get naming conflict with some built-in classes.

The closest to your try code:

```csharp
public ICommand MyCommand => new Command(parameter => { MyVoid(); });
```

or the same in "block" syntax

```csharp
public ICommand MyCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new Command(parameter => { MyVoid(); });
    }
}
```

But it's wrong approach because it will create new `Command` instance each time the command was called. Give to Garbage Collector as less work as possible. Examples of the correct ways doing it you may find below.

You're developing another bicycle. :) Look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern#relaying-command-logic).

Here is copy-paste from my project. It's exactly the same as in above link.

```xaml
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    private readonly Func<object, bool> _canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);
    public void Execute(object parameter) => _execute(parameter);
}
```

And the usage

```xaml
<Button Contecnt="Click me!" Command="{Binding MyCommand}"/>
```

```csharp
private ICommand _myCommand;

public ICommand MyCommand => _myCommand ?? (_myCommand = new RelayCommand(parameter =>
{
    // do here the execution
}));
```

And with `parameter` (`Binding` for `CommandParameter` is available too)

```xaml
<Button Contecnt="Click me!" Command="{Binding MyCommand}" CommandParameter="test value"/>
```

```csharp
public ICommand MyCommand => _myCommand ?? (_myCommand = new RelayCommand(parameter =>
{
    if (parameter is string p && p == "test value")
    {
        // do here the execution
    }
}));
```

And finally, usage of optional `CanExecute`

```xaml
public ICommand MyCommand => _myCommand ?? (_myCommand = new RelayCommand(parameter =>
{
    // do here the execution
    // don't put the same condition as in CanExecute here,
    // it was already checked before execution has entered this block
},
parameter => (x > y) && (a + b > c) // any condition or just return a bool
));
```

if `CanExecute` returns `false`, the command will not be executed and `Button` or `MenuItem` becomes automatically disabled. Just test it.