# c# MVVM: How to bind 2 ContentControls to 2 Properties of MainViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm working on a daily task manager.

I want to display 2 different views inside of 2 different ContentControls in my MainWindow.xaml.
I have a ViewModelMain, which contains two properties of type ViewModelBase. So I can switch between different ViewModels, because they all implement the ViewModelBase, which implements INotifyPropertyChanged. With just one ContentControl it is no Problem to choose any view. In fact it is possible (when configured in the Command) to select the viewmodels from the second ContentControl correctly.

Now I need help... why is my second ContentControl not displaying anything?
I've tried to evaluate, where the problem is, but the ViewModel selection is passed as expected and the OnPropertyChanged Method is called.

Thanks for your help.

My ViewModelMain:

```cs
public class ViewModelMain : ViewModelBase {

        private ViewModelBase selectedVMMain;
        private ViewModelBase selectedVMEssentail;


        public ViewModelBase SelectedVMMain {
            get { return selectedVMMain; }
            set {
                if( selectedVMMain != value ) {
                    selectedVMMain = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(selectedVMMain));
                }
            }
        }
        public ViewModelBase SelectedVMEssential {
            get { return selectedVMEssentail; }
            set {
                if( selectedVMEssentail != value ) {
                    selectedVMEssentail = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(selectedVMEssentail));
                }
            }
        }

        public ICommand CommandUpdateView { get; set; }

        public ViewModelMain() {
            this.CommandUpdateView = new CommandUpdateView(this);
        }

}
```

CommandUpdateView:

```
private ViewModelMain viewModelMain;
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public CommandUpdateView( ViewModelMain _viewModelMain) {
            this.viewModelMain = _viewModelMain;
        }

        public bool CanExecute( object parameter ) => true;
        public void Execute( object parameter ) {
            switch( parameter ) {

            case nameof(EnumViewModels.Übersicht):
                viewModelMain.SelectedVMMain = new ViewModelÜbersicht();
                break;
            case nameof(EnumViewModels.Statistik):
                viewModelMain.SelectedVMMain = new ViewModelStatistik();
                break;

            case nameof(EnumViewModels.Kategorie):
                viewModelMain.SelectedVMEssential = new ViewModelKategorie();
                break;
            case nameof(EnumViewModels.Projekt):
                viewModelMain.SelectedVMEssential = new ViewModelProjekt();
                break;
            case nameof(EnumViewModels.Aufgabe):
                viewModelMain.SelectedVMEssential = new ViewModelAufgabe();
                break;
            case nameof(EnumViewModels.Pomodoro):
                viewModelMain.SelectedVMEssential = new ViewModelPomodoro();
                break;

            default:
                viewModelMain.SelectedVMMain = new ViewModelTEST();
                viewModelMain.SelectedVMEssential = new ViewModelTEST();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

MainWindow.xaml (DataContext is set to new ViewModelMain)

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="100" Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="200" Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="200" Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                    Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
                    Margin="5" Width="100" >

            <Button x:Name="Button_Uebersicht" Content="Übersicht"
                    Command="{Binding CommandUpdateView}" CommandParameter="Übersicht"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                    Margin="0,5" />
            <Button x:Name="Button_Statistik" Content="Statistik" 
                    Command="{Binding CommandUpdateView}" CommandParameter="Statistik"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Margin="0,5" />
            <Button x:Name="Button_Kategorie" Content="Kategorie" 
                    Command="{Binding CommandUpdateView}" CommandParameter="Kategorie"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Margin="0,5" />
            <Button x:Name="Button_Projekt" Content="Projekt" 
                    Command="{Binding CommandUpdateView}" CommandParameter="Projekt"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Margin="0,5" />
            <Button x:Name="Button_Aufgabe" Content="Aufgabe" 
                    Command="{Binding CommandUpdateView}" CommandParameter="Aufgabe"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Margin="0,5" />
            <Button x:Name="Button_Pomodoro" Content="Pomodoro" 
                    Command="{Binding CommandUpdateView}" CommandParameter="Pomodoro"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Margin="0,5" />

            <Button x:Name="Button_TEST" Content="TEST" 
                    Command="{Binding CommandUpdateView}"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Margin="0,5" />

        </StackPanel>

        <ContentControl x:Name="CC_Main"
                        Content="{Binding SelectedVMMain}"
                        Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"
                        Margin="5" Width="Auto"/>
        <ContentControl x:Name="CC_Essential"
                        Content="{Binding SelectedVMEssential}"
                        Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0"
                        Margin="5" Width="Auto"/>
```

Comment: Do you have an appropriate DataTemplate for your view-models used in the second ContentControl? Also, have you tried using Snoop/Visual Studio at runtime to make sure the binding is working properly and that the DataContext is correct on the second ContentControl?

Comment: I have set the DataContext of the Mainwindow to the ViewModelMain. If I declare the ViewModelMain as a variable and add it to the context of the MainWindow and the second ContentControl it is still the same, so thats not the problem. Also the DataTemplates are Correct, because if I use the first Content Control to display the ViewModels it works! Can you explain, what you mean, by checking the binding?

Comment: You're instantiating new VM object on each command call. Try to instantiate it once and then assign existing VM to `SelectedVMEssential` on command call.

Comment: And consider improving the `ICommand` implementation as it suggested [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern#relaying-command-logic) and in the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61463227). For now, it's difficult to understand, what your code do and how VMs initializing, where it initially get its values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

It was the field, which was misspelled... the Property was named correctly, but the the Binding didn't work  because, i used the nameof(field) keyword...

Thanks for the nice introduction on Stack Overflow!!!